# What is the best way to add bindings and get bindings when you have lots of fields to bind in Excel. Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js

What is the best way to add bindings and get bindings when you have lots of fields to bind in Excel.  Office.js

I am currently doing the following for each and every field i bind in excel.  Seems like there would be a better way possibly?  #1 is the adding of each field and #2 is the getting of each field.

1. ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("FieldId", "Range", "FieldId");
2. ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("FieldId").getRange().values = [[model.FieldId]];

```js
 public Bind() {
        return Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field1", "Range", "Field1");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field2", "Range", "Field2");
     ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field3", "Range", "Field3");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field4", "Range", "Field4");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field5", "Range", "Field5");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field6", "Range", "Field6");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field7", "Range", "Field7");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field8", "Range", "Field8");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field9", "Range", "Field9");
            ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Field10", "Range", "Field10");

            return ctx.sync();
        }).catch(ErrorHandler);
    }

    public Get() {
        return Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
            var field1 = Office.context.document.settings.get("Field1");
            if (field1 === null) {
                field1 = await this.SelectField1();
            }

            return $.post({
                url: 'getUrl',
                data: { id: field1 }
            }).done(async (model) => {
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field1").getRange().values = [[model.Field1]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field2").getRange().values = [[model.Field2]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field3").getRange().values = [[model.Field3]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field4").getRange().values = [[model.Field4]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field5").getRange().values = [[model.Field5]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field6").getRange().values = [[model.Field6]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field7").getRange().values = [[model.Field7]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field8").getRange().values = [[model.Field8]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field9").getRange().values = [[model.Field9]];
                ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Field10").getRange().values = [[model.Field10]];

                // Sync to update sheet in Excel
                await ctx.sync();
            });
        }).catch(ErrorHandler);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you feel should be better?  Also, a more complete code snippet might help in explaining what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft seems like maybe there is a better way to add bindings and get bindings.  We are going to have a lot of fields.  See my added code to show you what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... you can always do a loop.  For example, for adding:

```
const fieldNames = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5");

return Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
    fieldNames.forEach(name =>
        ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem(name, "Range", name)
    );
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(ErrorHandler);
```

Or, for retrieving:

```
const fieldNames = ["Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5");

return Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
let ranges = fieldNames.map(name =>
        ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem().getRange().load("values")
    );
    return ctx.sync();

    ranges.forEach(r => console.log(r.value));
 }).catch(ErrorHandler);
```

Does that help?